# JAX-WS generated classes to Database tables mapping

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, orm, jax-ws

What is the easiest way to put generated by `JAX-WS` classes to the oracle database (in other words i need to have set of insert statements per each Java object)? Only ORM like `jpa/hibernate`? any alternatives?

roundabout way is to check each class fields by reflection to get their names (annotated with `@XMLElement` annotation and currently equal to column names) to obtain column names for `INSERT` statements.

pros/cons?)

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to persist the XML because this wont require a mapping to any other model nor will it require any reflection to determine a model to persist. Most databases will have an XML data type these days which make storing more efficient, even queries can be efficient with indexing xpaths.

Alternatively you can go down the path you've suggested.

Finally you can create your own model to and then use JPA/hibernate to persist that into the database. You'll need to map the generated classes to your model (using something like dozer framework). This will require the most work however will you give the most flexibility (possibly).